# Are Anonymous Classes a bad idea?

Tags: java

After using them a while I can't help but feel that the hoops you're forced to jump through when using anonymous classes are not worth it.

You end up with `final` all over the place and no matter what the code is more difficult to read than if you'd used a well named inner class.

So what are the advantages of using them?  I must be missing something.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The advantage is that it's an implementation of closures. It's clunky, but it's the best we've got in Java at the moment. In other words, you don't have to create a new class just for the sake of preserving some state which you've already got as a local variable somewhere.

I have [an article comparing C# and Java closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx), and why they're useful in the first place, which might help.

Comment: I was under the impression that Java's anonymous inner classes did NOT close on their environment, but don't have a citation or example to support myself.

Comment: They do, but the only variables you can access from the outer scope are those which are declared final.

Comment: I'm not sure about this either.  If I understand closures, you can pass around a reference to a closure and it retains references to the bound variables of the enclosing scope where it was created.  I think that's missing in anonymous classes in Java.

Comment: It basically fake closures. It copies the values into the new class. Given that you've only got read-only access anyway, and the variables are final, it's reasonably close to closures. It's a copy of the environment instead of the environment itself, but that's very often close enough.

Comment: Is this still best practice sir?

Answer (score 4):

Well I usually only use it when needing an implementation of an interface for a single purpose (and an interface with few functions or the code because really fast ugly)...
like in the following example :

```
this.addListener(new IListener(){
    public void listen() {...}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally limit anonymous classes to just a few lines. Anything longer than, say 5, make a named class.

Comment: Or at least a static nested class

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [this article](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3300881) that I found very enlightening.

You say that **final** keyword is all over the place but, with a local class, you still have to pass the state of the enclosing class which can also be bad for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Anynomous classes can be useful. But what I have often seen was not useful. A lot of anonymous class were too large and reduced the readability. Some experts use many identical anonymous classes. There is no strict rule when it is good idea to use an anonymous class or not but there are thumb rules:

1. Large and complex classes should not be anonymous.
2. The readability of the container class must be guaranteed.
3. DRY - don't repeat yourself. Don't create two identical anonymous class.
4. If you have a lot of non-identical but similar anonymous classes then you should identify the parts of these classes that you can reuse. Try to use the  template method pattern.

It is important for the quality of the code and the software to reduce redundant. "Copy and paste" is an antipattern in programming because the original piece of code can contain a bug. If someone copies that piece of code then he duplicate the bug. Ten weeks later someone else find the bug and fix it but the other bug is still in the code and it takes additional ten weeks to find and fix it. W